# aria2c to download and extract .tar.bz2 file

Tags: aria2

I am using `aria2c` to download a `.tar.bz2` and trying to extract it in the same command. I can download the file but not extract it.  Thank you :).

```
aria2c -x8 -l log.txt -c -d /xx/xx/xxx --use-head=true --http-user "<user>"  --http-passwd >password> http://xxx.xx/xxx/xx/xxx/xxxx/xx/xxx.tar.bz2 | tar xj
bzip2: (stdin) is not a bzip2 file.
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it at one go with aria2.

You ask `aria2c` to download the file using multiple connections (with `-x8` option). Therefore it cannot output what it downloads to `stdout`.

As far as I know, `aria2c` supports output to file only.

So if you'd like to use aria2c multi-segmented download feature, you have to run `aria2c` to download the file. When download is complete, use `tar` to extract it.

Otherwise, use `wget`:

```
wget -O - -o log.txt --http-user=<user> --http-password=<password> \
     http://xxx.xx/xxx.tar.bz2 | tar xj
```